# how to maintain the app 1*1 widget after reboot without shared preference

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I have created 1*1 widget.The layout of the widget contains ImageView ,the image of the image view is set like this

```
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_appwidget_small);
    Intent defineIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    defineIntent.putExtra("from_widget", true);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1;   
    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.img_widget,R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    defineIntent.putExtra("type_from_widget", 1);
    pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, defineIntent, 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.img_widget, pendingIntent1);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(intExtra, views);
```

But I select image for ImageView by checking some condition in the ConfigurationActivity.
I am storing the details of the widget in the shared preference with AppWidgetId and maintaining it after reboot,it takes a few seconds to load .
Another main reason widget goes blank when the device is rebooted after the app data is cleared

storing the data in shared  preference.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(MainActivity.widgetBeanArrayList);
edit.putString("widget_arraylist", json);
edit.commit();
```

retrieving it in onReceive method of AppWidgetProvider class and maintain my widget

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if(intent.getBooleanExtra("from_config_activity",false)){
        for (int mAppWidgetId : intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS)) {
            update(mAppWidgetId,intent.getIntExtra("image_id",0));
        }
    }
    if(intent.getBooleanExtra("switch_on",false)){

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
                .getInstance(context);
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
        if(settings != null) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = settings.getString("widget_arraylist", null);
            Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<WidgetBean>>() {}.getType();
            MainActivity.widgetBeanArrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);

            if(MainActivity.widgetBeanArrayList!=null) {
                if (MainActivity.widgetBeanArrayList.size() > 0){
                    for(int i = 0;i < MainActivity.widgetBeanArrayList.size();i++){
                        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_appwidget_small);
                        if(MainActivity.widgetBeanArrayList.get(i).icon == 1) {
                            views.setImageViewResource(R.id.img_widget, R.drawable.feed_detail_share);
                        }else if(MainActivity.widgetBeanArrayList.get(i).icon == 2){
                            views.setImageViewResource(R.id.img_widget, R.drawable.feed_detail_edit);
                        }else if(MainActivity.widgetBeanArrayList.get(i).icon == 3){
                            views.setImageViewResource(R.id.img_widget, R.drawable.feed_list_audio);
                        }
                        Intent defineIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                        defineIntent.putExtra("from_widget", true);
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, defineIntent, 0);
                        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.img_widget, pendingIntent1);
                        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(MainActivity.widgetBeanArrayList.get(i).id, views);
                    }

                }
            }

        }else{
            Log.d("tag", "=============settingd=====null===");
        }
    }
```

I have to maintain the widget Image without storing the details in  shared preference .
Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to make logic after rebooting device in onEnabled().

```
   @Override
      public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created(this callback gonna be first after rebooting device)
        final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = 
       AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        int widgets_IDs[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, AppWidgetProvider.class));
        for (int widget_id : widgets_IDs) {
         //...get data from shared preference and fill ur widgets by ids
        }
    }
```

After app data deleted, where is no proper way to return back the current state of widgets. So just move your user on configure activity to let him choose new settings for widgets